# Extend/override Eloquent create method - Cannot make static method non static

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm overriding the `create()` Eloquent method, but when I try to call it I get `Cannot make static method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::create() non static in class MyModel`.

I call the `create()` method like this:

```
$f = new MyModel();
$f->create([
    'post_type_id' => 1,
    'to_user_id' => Input::get('toUser'),
    'from_user_id' => 10,
    'message' => Input::get('message')
]);
```

And in the `MyModel` class I have this:

```
public function create($data) {
    if (!Namespace\Auth::isAuthed())
        throw new Exception("You can not create a post as a guest.");

    parent::create($data);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As the error says: The method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create()` is static and cannot be overridden as non-static.

So implement it as

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function create($data)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

and call it by `MyModel::create([...]);`

You may also rethink if the auth-check-logic is really part of the Model or better moving it to the Controller or Routing part.

**UPDATE**

This approach does not work from version 5.4.* onwards, instead follow [this answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17876#issuecomment-279026028).

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = static::query()->create($attributes);

    // ...

    return $model;
}
```

Comment: I gave this a +1 for the "rethink" statement! This logic doesn't belong to the MyModel class.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are overriding it and in the parent class it is defined as `static`. 
Try adding the word `static` in your function definition:

```
public static function create($data)
{
   if (!Namespace\Auth::isAuthed())
    throw new Exception("You can not create a post as a guest.");

   return parent::create($data);
}
```

Of course you will also need to invoke it in a static manner:

```
$f = MyModel::create([
    'post_type_id' => 1,
    'to_user_id' => Input::get('toUser'),
    'from_user_id' => 10,
    'message' => Input::get('message')
]);
```