# Extending Laravel create(): Why do docs say to override a non-static method as static?

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

I have a Laravel project that I'm upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4, following the [Laravel upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade).

In the guide it says that the create methods have been moved to the Builder class, and that this method should be called the new way `$model = static::query()->create($attributes);`.  As well as being documented in the upgrade guide, there are many questions across the internet, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404030/extend-override-eloquent-create-method-cannot-make-static-method-non-static) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17876#issuecomment-279026028).

The part I don't understand is why they still specify the overriding method as static.  The new create method is no longer static (hence the new call) but, all the examples still define a static method to override it.  If I do this, PHPStorm gives me the following (expected) error:

> Cannot make non static method Builder->create([attributes : array = []]) static

Why do examples (official docs included) override this as static?

Assuming there's a reason it works for everybody else, why doesn't mine work?

Comment: Are you defining yours in your model? It's technically no longer an override since the parent method was removed, you keep it static to maintain the signature.

Comment: @apokryfos I have it in a class that extends Model and PHPStorm says "Overrides method in class 'Builder'".
Is it the case that my code could be correct and I don't want PHPStorm to think that it is an overriden method?

Apologies for the delay, I'm only working part-time but, I do want to solve my problem.

Comment: I should not say that. If you're using any sort of ide helpers like e.g. [this one](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) then you should refresh it for L5.4. Also make sure you're not declaring `@mixin Builder` in your model. At any rate, PhpStorm would not be correct in assuming that a method in your Model would override a method in Builder since model has no direct relationship with builder.

Comment: So, it turns out...
Nowhere in my code do I have the mixin Builder tag but, the Laravel code "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent" does contain "@mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder" in the doc comment for abstract class Model.

But, I changed composer laravel version from 5.4.* (as the upgrade guide says) to 5.4.0 and the @mixin tags are no longer there and therefore, the error is gone.

This is great (yay!) but, what then happens when there's an update and they get added back in?  I don't see an upgrade guide for 5.4.*.

Comment: I don't think it would be added back in without a good reason. It's definitely not in there in 5.5 which I'm using. However `@mixin` is just a documentation hint which PhpStorm reads and assumes it's accurate. Unlike code, you can't really unit-test comments or documentation so there's always a chance the documentation lags behind the actual changes. I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: The mixin builder tag is added in Laravel version 5.4.29.  The latest version is 5.4.36.

Comment: It's good to know it's not there in 5.5 and you're very right about not really being able to test comments/documentation.  I'll avoid versions with the tag while I upgrade knowing that it will be fixed again on the next upgrade or so.  Thank you for your help!

Would you like to make an answer so I can accept it and you can have credit for knowing what causes the problem?  I'm not sure if I'm high enough reputation to upvote it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a very short explanation to what is going on here. The Laravel eloquent model in 5.3 and earlier had the `create` method within its own class as a static function. This was the source:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);
    $model->save();
    return $model;
}
```

At the same time the model had the following `__call` definition.

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }
    return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

This meant that every function call that was not defined on the model would be called on a new instance of a `Builder` object.

In 5.4 they decided that `create` seems like a better fit in `Builder` rather than the model itself so they made this method there:

```
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

it essentially does the same thing but it fits better in the builder, however the notable difference is that **it is not static** because all static-like calls on the model are forwarded to a `Builder` *instance*.

If you did override the method before in subclasses and then called `parent::create` at some point, this would probably no longer work since parent didn't really have a create, therefore the alternative code of `static::query()->create(...)` was suggested. In practice calling `$this->__call('create', ...)` would also probably work but that is very hard to read and will mess up IDEs doing refactoring because it's an undetectable call the `Builder::create`.

Now the last bit is that the `Model` also had `@mixin Builder` on it. `@mixin` indicates that  a class is basically mixed in the current class to extend its functionality and is used to hint to the IDE that this is happening when it happens in non-standard OOP ways (like with `__call` and `__callStatic` in this case). This caused your IDE to think that you're overloading `create` on `Builder` due to the IDE thinking that `Builder` was mixed in with `Model` however the reality is that it wasn't exactly mixed in but rather mixed in as statics (as far as I know PhpStorm has trouble dealing with this concept)

So there it is. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: A great explanation, thank you.  For others with the same problem, these are the versions that cause/solve the problem.  The breaking mixin tag is introduced in Laravel 5.4.29, so for those updating to 5.4, you'll want 5.4.28.  If using barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper, version "^2.4" (I think that's basically 2.x where x > 4) automatically inserts the breaking mixin tag, so you're best to use ">=2.3 <2.4", which specifies the latest release between laravel 5.4 and 5.5 support.  Thanks again!